# Test Class Help Needed. Assertion is failing, and I can not figure out the cause

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Below is my test class and class that is to be tested against. I am getting an assertion fail on line 105 (Well all of the assertion lines on 104, 105 and 106 of method tm2.  I can not figure out why this is happening as I am calling a variable that should have the information needed and it seems as if the fields I am attempting to assert against are null. Can you help?  Thank you in advance!

Test Class -

```
@isTest
public class AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test{

    public static Case testCase;
    public static AVISPL_Service_Maintenance_Contract__c testSmc;
    public static Account testAcc;

    @testSetup
    private static void myTestData(){
       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'Test Warehouse Account';
        a.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        a.RecordTypeId = '01240000000DhQMAA0';
        a.Named_Account__c = 'No';
        a.Exclusive_Account__c = 'No';
        a.Enterprise_Account__c = 'No';
       insert a;
       AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testAcc = a;
       System.debug('The new Account ID is ' + a.Id);


       Contact con = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = 'Test Shawn';
        con.LastName = 'Contact';
        con.Email = 'djsuite015@gmail.com';
        con.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        con.AccountId = '0014000000iLrfy';
        con.RecordTypeId = '012330000001HMuAAM';
       insert con;
       System.debug('The new Contact ID is ' + con.Id);


       AVISPL_Service_Level_Term__c sla = new AVISPL_Service_Level_Term__c();
        sla.Name = 'Test';
        sla.Active__c = True;
       insert sla;
       system.debug('The new SLA Term ID is ' + sla.Id);


       AVISPL_Service_Maintenance_Contract__c s = new AVISPL_Service_Maintenance_Contract__c();
        s.Name = 'Warehouse Test SMC';
        s.Active_Contract__c = True;
        s.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        s.Salesperson__c = con.Id;
        s.BKR_Customer__c = '12345';
        s.Company_Database__c = 'AVI';
        s.Contract_Job_Number__c = '010S';
        s.Contract_Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2016, 11, 1);
        s.Contract_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2017, 11, 1);
        s.SLA_Terms__c = sla.Id;
        s.Sale_Type__c = 'Service Only - Net New';
       // s.Preventative_Maintenance_Visits__c = 'One';
        s.RecordTypeId = '012330000001HMpAAM';
       insert s;
       AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testSmc = s;
       system.debug('The new SMC Id is ' + s.Id);

       Case c = new Case();
        c.RecordTypeId = '01240000000INaqAAG';
        c.Status = 'New / Open';
        c.Priority = 'P4';
        c.Department__c = 'Help Desk';
        c.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        c.AccountId = a.Id;
        c.AVISPL_Service_Maintenance_Contract__c = s.Id;
        c.Sub_Account_Room_Information__c = 'TBD';
        c.Type = 'Contract';
        c.Origin = 'Phone';
        c.Subject = 'Test';
        c.Description = 'Test';
        c.Svc_Category_Client_Reported_Issue__c = 'A/V';
        c.New_Job_Number__c = '';
       insert c;
       AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase = c;
       system.debug('The testCase ID is ' + testCase.Id);
       system.debug('The new Case Id is ' + c.Id);

    }

   private static testMethod void tm1(){
      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.myTestData();
      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase = [SELECT id, New_Job_Number__c, AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c,Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c
                                                  FROM Case WHERE id = :AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.Id];
      If(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.New_Job_Number__c != null) {
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith('010S'));
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c == 'FL_Tampa_010S_100600_AVI');
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c == '010S');
       }
   }

    private static testMethod void tm2(){
       String jobNumber = '780S';
       String wCode = 'AB_Calgary_780S_780600_CAD';

      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.myTestData();
      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase = [SELECT id, New_Job_Number__c, AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c,Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c
                                                  FROM Case WHERE id = :AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.Id];
      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testSmc.Contract_Job_Number__c = jobNumber;
      update AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testSmc;
      AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.Priority = 'P3';
      update AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase;

      If(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.New_Job_Number__c != null) {
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith('780S'));
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c == 'AB_Calgary_780S_780600_CAD');
        system.assert(AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code_Test.testCase.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c == jobNumber);
       }
   }

}
```

Class to be tested -

```
public class AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code {
    public static void setWarehouseCode(List<Case> CaseWar) {
        FOR(Case c:CaseWar){
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('780S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'AB_Calgary_780S_780600_CAD';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '780S';                
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('250S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'CA_San Francisco_250S_250600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '250S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('010S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Tampa_010S_100600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '010S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('020S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Orlando_020S_200600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '020S';   
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('030S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Ft. Lauderdale_030S_300600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '030S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('040S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Tallahassee_040S_400600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '040S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('050S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Jacksonville_050S_500600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '050S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('070S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'AL_Huntsville_070S_070600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '070S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('080S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'GA_Atlanta_080S_080600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '080S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('140S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'FL_Tampa CRG_140S_140600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '140S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('160S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'WA_Seattle_160S_160600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '160S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('170S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'MN_St. Paul_170S_170600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '170S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('200S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'TX_Dallas Integration_200S_150600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '200S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('240S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'PA_Philadelphia_240S_240600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '240S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('260S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'VA_Sterling_260S_260600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '260S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('270S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'OH_Dayton_270S_270600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '270S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('310S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'CO_Denver_310S_310600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '310S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('360S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'NC_Greensboro_360S_360600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '360S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('380S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'MD_Performance_380S_380600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '380S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('410S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'CA_Los Angeles_410S_410600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '410S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('490S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'NY_Long Island City_490S_490600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '490S';                
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('600S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'IL_Chicago_600S_600600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '600S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('610S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'MI_Detroit_610S_610600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '610S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('620S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'OH_Cleveland_620S_620600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '620S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('630S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'PA_Pittsburgh_630S_630600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '630S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('640S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'TX_Houston_640S_640600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '640S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('670S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'MD_Columbia Integration_670S_670600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '670S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('782S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'ON_Ottawa_782S_100600_CAD';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '782S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('850Y')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'EU_EMEA & United Kingdom_850Y_100600_UK';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '850Y';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('890S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'MA_Boston_890S_890600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '890S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('900S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'DC_Washington, DC_900S_900600_AVI';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '900S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('781S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'QC_Montreal_781S_100600_CAD';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '781S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('783S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'ON_Toronto_783S_100600_CAD';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '783S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('390S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'AE_Dubai_390S_390600_SPL';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '390S';
            }
            IF(c.New_Job_Number__c.startsWith ('785S')){
                c.AVI_SPL_Rep_Whse_Office_Code_2011__c = 'BC_Vancouver_785S_785600_CAD';
                c.Salesperson_Extraction_Code__c = '785S';
            }

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not null or it would not enter the checks. What is the assertion telling you?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the testdata you are doing this in the case creation:

```
c.New_Job_Number__c = '';
```

The code checks for the new_job_number and then fills the other fields based on that. But if the new_job_number is empty, nothing will happen and the asserts will fail.

I can see you do fill the new job number on  `AVISPL_Service_Maintenance_Contract__c` but not on `Case`!

Also the `setWarehouseCode` method in the `AVI_SPL_Set_Warehouse_Code` class is never called, but I assume that happens in the Case trigger?

Comment: Correct, that happens in the case trigger.  Sorry yes that can be misleading...there is another case trigger that populates the c.New_Job_Number field, and that is why I set it to blank to cause an update to c before the assertions to allow the other trigger to fire and re-populate the New_Job_Number field with the appropriate value.

Comment: the issue might be in trigger order then? As triggers run in random order.. Can you see in the debug logs which trigger runs first?

Comment: Yes I did that and they are running int he correct order. :(  Thanks for the brainstorming with me!

Comment: maybe worth a try to set it once in the testcode and see what happens..?